# WS02mi adding default xmlns in SOAP Response

Tags: wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I'm using WS02 micro integrator for REST to SOAP orchestration. WS02mi payload mediator factory used to return the SOAP response to upstream system but response getting rejected with 406 error,

The below is the SOAP response,

```
    <soapenv:Envelope
        xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soapenv:Body>
            <xsd:ATService.QueryDNResult
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.XXXX.com/YYYY/xsd">
                <retData>
                    <retCode>
                        rcSuccess
                        </retCode>
                    <retMsg>
                        Okay
                        </retMsg>
                    </retData>
                <queryDNReplyList>
                    <item>
                        <dn>670000001</dn>
                        <resourceState>Active</resourceState>
                        <notes>Data Load</notes>
                        <acquiredFrom/>
                        <customer/>
                       </item>
                    </queryDNReplyList>
                </xsd:ATService.QueryDNResult>
            </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
```

But upstream rejects the response with below error,

```
<soapenv:Envelope
        xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soapenv:Body>
            <Error
                xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
                406
                </Error>
            </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
```

I'm not setting the xmlns in the response but ws02mi injects during the response. Any options to remove/suppress this default xmlns in my response?